# Insert/Add a test step in the first or in the middle of two steps in QC using OTA

Tags: ota

I am using the following code to insert a new linkTest Step in HPQC Test Plan.

```
Dim DSFactory, newLinkedDesignStep
Set DSFactory = objTest.DesignStepFactory
Set newLinkedDesignStep = DSFactory.AddItem(null)
newLinkedDesignStep.LinkTest = objLinkedTest
newLinkedDesignStep.Post
```

The code works awesome in doing its job, but it will add the step as a last step in the existing Test Case.

My requirement is that the step should be added in the top of existing steps(As a first step) or I should be able to insert a step in the middle of two steps or I should be able to re- arrange the steps in the required order.

Will it be possible using OTA, any suggestion is much appriciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Below code works for inserting a step in required order.

```
    Set DSFactory = TestCase.DesignStepFactory
    Dim aFilter As TDFilter
    Set aFilter = DSFactory.Filter
    Set newLinkedDesignStep = DSFactory.AddItem(Null)
    newLinkedDesignStep.LinkTest = objLinkedTest(1)
    newLinkedDesignStep("DS_STEP_ORDER") = stepID (Index Starts from 0)
    newLinkedDesignStep.Post
```